# pass a null as a one param argument

Tags: c#

I have a method that accepts `params` as a parameter to check if a property has invalid value or not. If the property has an invalid value, it throws an exception

```
private void ShouldNotEqual<T>(Expression<Func<Ticket, T>> outExpr, params object[] notValidPropertyValue)
```

The usage is:

```
ShouldNotEqual(student => student.Name, "jack", string.Empty);
ShouldNotEqual(student => student.Address, string.Empty, null);
```

The problem with this implementation is when I want to check a property against `null`, the parameter `notValidPropertyValue` is set as null, not an array with one element whose value is equal to `null`.

```
// I need to use it in this way
ShouldNotEqual(student => student.Phone, null); // Throws NullReferenceException for notValidPropertyValue
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: Shouldnt that signature be `params T[] notValidPropertyValue` ?? Lots of boxing/unboxing going on otherwise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you want `null` in the array and not just an empty array?

If you want `null`, use

```
var array = new object[] { null };
```

to create an array containing one value, `null`.

Then call `ShouldNotEqual` with the array, e.g.

```
ShouldNotEqual(student => student.Phone, array);
```

Or just inline it:

```
ShouldNotEqual(student => student.Phone, new object[] { null });
```

---

If you want an empty array, then just use

```
ShouldNotEqual(student => student.Phone, new object[0]);
```

Answer (score 2):

Explicitly pass an `object[]`:

```
ShouldNotEqual(student => student.Phone, new object[] { null });
```

Or add an overload to prevent this happening:

```
private void ShouldNotEqual<T>(
    Expression<Func<Ticket, T>> outExpr,
    object notValidPropertyValue)
{
    ShouldNotEqual(outExpr, new object[] { notValidPropertyValue });
}
```

This will take precedence when a single object, or `null` is passed.